# Is there a way to exclude certain sites from search results in Safari?

Tags: safari, spam, search-engine

I would like to make sure that junk websites (like SparkNotes when I search for Shakespeare info, or Pinterest when I search for images) don't appear in my search results in Google or any search engine. Some search engines support this, and Google used to but no longer does. But in any case what I'm looking for is something that does this for both macOS and iOS, and works in Safari (especially for Google).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I *think* there used to be a Chrome plugin for only google, you could search for that but you may have to get used to adding @Redarm's solution to your search toolkit. Annoying but it works...

Answer (score 2):

If you put `-site:pinterest.*` after an image search, it doesn't show any pinterest results in a Google search.

E.g. `image -site:pinterest.*`